# After scrolling on IPad, some content of my website is hidden behind a white area

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, reactjs

***Introduction***

We're developing a website and on one page we'd like to display some simple charts. Therefore we're using canvas to draw the charts. I konw there are other great libraries therefore, but right know we just need a quick and dirty solution for a first shot. Generally we work with Typescript and React.

The error occurs on a iPad (iOS 8.3) in Safari and Chrome 43.0. The page works fine on my Windows 7 computer in Firefox, Chrome 43.0, IE and even on my iPhone 4s.

***Description of the problem***

I'm not quite happy about how I described the problem below, but I don't know if the hidden content is not rendered correctly, it is overlayed or not displayed for any other reason. I just wrote what I see (or not see in my case).

The **page loads** without errors on the iPad.
[image: Page loads correctly]

When **scrolling down** (with one or two fingers), the page slides up. In the first moment I can see the content which is coming into view correctly. After less than a second, some content, which was outside of the viewport before scrolling, seems to be hidden behind a white area. The hidden content is within a div element. The canvas elements are always displayed correctly!
[image: After scrolling down, content which was outside of the viewport is hidden/not displayed]

When **scrolling up** again, the same happens for the content which was outside of the viewport before scrolling up (this content was displayed correctly after loading the page). Some content which was not displayed correctly after scrolling down is visible now, some is still hidden.
[image: After scrolling up again, some (other) parts of the page are hidden/not displayed]

I'm using an event listener to resize the canvas when necessary. I checked the event listener and it is only active when the page was resized (for the iPad that means the orientation changed).

***Code***

Here is the **HTML** code of one tile, containing the title, the list and the canvas. This code actually is a react component.

```
<div class="twocolumn" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0">
    <div class="column" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0">
        <div class="section" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.0">
            <div class="section-icon" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.0.0"></div>
            <span class="section-title" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.0.1">TITEL</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1">
            <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.0">rumpedibum:</span>
            <ul data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.1">
                <li data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.1.0">bla bla:</li>
                <li data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.1.1">bla bla:</li>
                <li data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.1.2">bla bla:</li>
                <li data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.1.3">bla bla:</li>
                <li data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.1.4">bla bla:</li>
                <li data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.0.1.1.5">bla bla:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.1"><div data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.1.0">
        <canvas class="linechart-maincanvas" width="438" height="180" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$wrap-.0.0.0.1.0.0"></canvas>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** code of one tile

```
.twocolumn {
  position: relative;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 14pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.twocolumn > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.twocolumn > div:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.twocolumn > div:not(:first-child) {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
.twocolumn > div:not(:first-child) > div {
  height: 180px;    // set canvas hight here
}
/**
 * A section title.
 */
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 20pt;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.section > .section-title {
  font-size: 11pt;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/**
* This is normal text in the left column
*/
.content {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this issue in a minimal environment?

Comment: This is a not too uncommon issue in Safari. Have you searched around StackOverflow for similar issues? Without a complete reproduction it's difficult to say what's causing it. In older versions of Safari, it seemed due to memory usage in some cases.

Comment: generally i can recommend you to remove `>` from all css selectors, because react will often use/append its own html elements to the page.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: I've looked for a solution and there are a couple of scrolling issues but there wasn't anything that helped me. Safari and Chrome are up to date and it happens in both of them (I think they have the same rendering engine).

Comment: @marcel: Ok, I'll have a look into that. We're using lesscss to generate css and so fare use the '>'.

Comment: Chrome on the iPad uses the same rendering engine as safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing

```
overflow: hidden;
```

solved the problem. I think `overflow: hidden;` did cause the problem because `div.twocolumn` does not have a defined with and height.

Is this a bug on the iPad or do browsers on other platforms correct my mistake?